# odd even position of digits in a number

Tags: number-theory, combinatorial-number-theory

Please give answer of this question with explanation, There is a number 36867294. If the digits at even positions in the number are deleted, then which of the following could be the difference of two adjacent digits in the resultant number?

Please let me know if there is any specific rule in mathematics for deciding odd and even position in more than 5 digit number.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  I'd expect the numbering to go right to left, so $4$ is in the first position, $9$ is in the second, and so on.  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Apart from the possible confusion as to which are considered the even positions (*"positions" in my experience are usually counted from left to right starting from $1$*), all that should remain to the problem is reading comprehension and organizing results.  What number did you arrive at after having deleted the even positions of the original number?  What are the possible results of differences of adjacent digits in the result?

Comment: In the event that you don't know whether to interpret positions as being numbered from left to right or from right to left... *just say so* and then solve the question for each interpretation separately, stating the differences in assumptions used.  There is no shame in not knowing something like this.  In a testing environment, you are generally allowed to ask for clarification for things like this... *especially* since different conventions can be used in different places.

Comment: I want to ask position of each digit in given number 36867294. as per your knowledge which numbers are at odd positions and which are at even positions?